# How to handle generic types with different concrete types in rust efficiently?

Tags: rust

The main goal is to implement a computation graph, that handles nodes with values and nodes with operators (think of simple arithmetic operators like add, subtract, multiply etc..). An operator node can take up to two value nodes, and "produces" a resulting value node.

Up to now, I'm using an enum to differentiate between a value and operator node:

```
pub enum Node<'a, T> where T : Copy + Clone {
    Value(ValueNode<'a, T>),
    Operator(OperatorNode)
}

pub struct ValueNode<'a, T> {
   id: usize, 
   value_object : &'a dyn ValueType<T>
}
```

**Update**: `Node::Value` contains a struct, which itself contains a reference to a trait object `ValueType`, which is being implemented by a variety of concrete types.

But here comes the problem. During compililation, the generic types will be elided, and replaced by the actual types. The generic type `T` is also being propagated throughout the computation graph (obviously):

```
pub struct ComputationGraph<T> where T : Copy + Clone {
    nodes: Vec<Node<T>>
}
```

This actually restricts the usage of `ComputeGraph` to one specific `ValueType`.

Furthermore the generic type `T` cannot be `Sized`, since a value node can be an opqaue type handled by a different backend not available through rust (think of C opqaue types made available through FFI).

One possible solution to this problem would be to introduce an additional enum type, that "mirrors" the concrete implementation of the valuetype trait mentioned above. this approach would be similiar, that [enum dispatch](https://docs.rs/enum_dispatch/0.1.2/enum_dispatch/) does.

Is there anything I haven't thought of to use multiple implementations of `ValueType`?

**update**:

What i want to achive is following code:

```
pub struct Scalar<T> where T : Copy + Clone{
    data : T
}

fn main() {
   let cg = ComputeGraph::new();

   // a new scalar type. doesn't have to be a tuple struct   
   let a = Scalar::new::<f32>(1.0);

   let b_size = 32; 
   let b = Container::new::<opaque_type>(32);

   let op = OperatorAdd::new();

   // cg.insert_operator_node constructs four nodes: 3 value nodes  
   // and one operator nodes internally. 
   let result = cg.insert_operator_node::<Container>(&op, &a, &b);

}
```

**update**

`ValueType<T>` looks like this

```
pub trait ValueType<T> {
    fn get_size(&self) -> usize;
    fn get_value(&self) -> T;
}
```

**update**

To further increase the clarity of my question think of a small BLAS library backed by OpenCL. The memory management and device interaction shall be transparent to the user. A Matrix type allocates space on an OpenCL device with types as a primitive type buffer, and the appropriate call will return a pointer to that specific region of memory. Think of an operation that will scale the matrix by a scalar type, that is being represented by a primitive value. Both the (pointer to the) buffer and the scalar can be passed to a kernel function. Going back to the `ComputeGraph`, it seems obvious, that all BLAS operations form some type of computational graph, which can be reduced to a linear list of instructions ( think here of setting kernel arguments, allocating buffers, enqueue the kernel, storing the result, etc... ). Having said all that, a computation graph needs to be able to store value nodes with a variety of types.

Comment: `Value(ValueType<T>)` is not a legal enum variant if `ValueType<T>` is a trait. This code doesn't make sense. *The generic type T is also being propagated throughout the computation graph* -- yes, that's what generics do, but *This actually restricts the usage of ComputeGraph to one specific ValueType* -- no, that doesn't make sense. What does your real code look like? Please try to create a [mre] -- either something that can be compiled, and has the wrong behavior, or something that expresses what you *want* to do, but doesn't compile.

Comment: you're right. I made a mistake concerning the enum enclosed types. That's actually a struct. I also updated my question.

Comment: and yes, I am well aware, that generics will be elided at compile time and replaced by the conrete type :)

Comment: You need to post the definition of the `ValueType` trait.

Comment: I'm still confused by "restricts the usage of `ComputeGraph` to one specific `ValueType`". Do you mean "to one specific `T`"? Because there can be multiple implementors of `ValueType<T>` for any given `T`. But if you're saying the problem is that making `ValueType` generic over `T` forces you to specify `T`, I don't understand that, either -- surely that's why you made `ValueType` generic over `T` in the first place, right? Or are you saying you don't know how to make `ValueType` *not* generic? (In which case, again, not really sure what the problem is due to lack of context)

Comment: i'm sorry for the confusion. Looks like I am still lacking some clarity. let me rephrase my question: "The graph should be able to accept all kinds of value types, but mostly restricted to primitve numeric types. How can that be achieved? Is the chosen infrastructed not suited for that task? Am i overthinking the problem?" As I mentioned in my question, there are opaque types, that must be handled as well. Coercing the opaue types into arch related pointers ( usize ) is not an optimal solution, as i want to avoid handling raw pointers in the higher level abstractions of the implemented system.

Comment: [@Peter Hall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/493729/peter-hall) as requested I did so now.

Comment: Possibly I am just being unreasonably thick skulled today. By "all kinds of value types", do you mean *all kinds of `T`s*, which is precluded by making the graph generic over `T`, or *all kinds of things that implement `ValueType<T>`*, which seems perfectly doable? In your example it's not clear to me what `T` is supposed to be in the type of `cg`.

Comment: Your questions about my main question are totally reasonable and fine and I disagree, that you are thick-skulled ;) The confusion is a result of constraining `ComputeGraph` to ONE generic type, so it is compilable, because a field also requires a generic type. This is, what i actually want to avoid. using all types doesn't make sense either. Being absurd, a fictional `Email` type wouldn't make much sense in this context, but I cannot think of more trait boundaries, that would constrain the generic type even further. I added a little bit of a higher level explanation of what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always the answer to the problem posed in the question is obvious. The graph expects one generic type (with trait bounds). Using an enum to "cluster" various subtypes was the solution, as already sketched out in the question.

An example to illustrate the solution. Consider following "subtypes":

```
struct Buffer<T> {
   // fields
}

struct Scalar<T> {
   // fields
}

struct Kernel {
   // fields
}
```

The value containing types can be packed into an enum:

```
enum MemType {
   Buffer(Buffer<f32>);
   Scalar(Scalar<f32>);
   // more enum variants ..
}
```

Now `MemType` and `Kernel` can now be packed in an enum as well

```
enum Node {
   Value(MemType);
   Operator(Kernel);
}
```

`Node` can now be used as the main type for nodes/vertices inside the graph. The solution might not be very elegant, but it does the trick for now. Maybe some code restructuring might be done in the future.